# SQL command not properly ended update

Tags: java, sql, oracle

When I try to execute the script below on Java I've got this exception :

**SQL command not properly ended**

I am using Java Swing and Oracle SQL

My string:

```
String sql= "update PROJEKT.PACJENT set IMIE='"+ jTextField9.getText() + "',NAZWISKO='"+ jTextField10.getText() + "',MIASTO='"+ jTextField11.getText() + "',ULICA='"+ jTextField12.getText() + "',UBEZPIECZENIE=" + jTextField13.getText() + "' where PESEL='" + jTextField8.getText()+ "'";
```

Comment: `System.out.println(sql)` and see what the string looks like - it's the easiest way to debug it. But you should alsl look at using PreparedStatement as it takes away all that pain of quoting your strings correctly

Comment: Your missing a single tick

Comment: Please learn how to use a `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because, you missed open `'` quote

```
UBEZPIECZENIE=" + jTextField13.getText() + "'
```

Also, you should use [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work for you:

```
String updateSQL = "update PROJEKT.PACJENT set IMIE=?, NAZWISKO=?, MIASTO=?, ULICA=?, UBEZPIECZENIE=? where PESEL=?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateSQL);
preparedStatement.setString(1, jTextField9.getText());
preparedStatement.setString(2, jTextField10.getText());
preparedStatement.setString(3, jTextField11.getText());
preparedStatement.setString(4, jTextField12.getText());
preparedStatement.setString(5, jTextField13.getText());
preparedStatement.setString(6, jTextField8.getText());
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```